# Query not bringing associated values with max function (Northwinds Database)

Tags: mysql, sql, max, greatest-n-per-group, northwind

I'm trying to get the product that has the highest gross value per category. I get the correct 'Grossed' amount by category, but it doesn't seem to bring the correct 'ProductID' and 'ProductName' with it.

```
SELECT 
    c.CategoryName,
    prodGross.ProductID,
    prodGross.ProductName,
    MAX(ROUND(Grossed, 2)) AS Grossed
FROM
    categories AS c
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        p.ProductID,
            p.ProductName,
            p.CategoryID,
            SUM(((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) - ((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * od.Discount))) AS Grossed
    FROM
        northwind.`order details` AS od
    JOIN products AS p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
    GROUP BY p.ProductID) AS prodGross ON prodGross.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
GROUP BY c.CategoryName;
```

Any feedback would be helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: This is an example of the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] question, which has dozens of solutions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I changed up my groupings. Now I get too much data back. The categories show all products and the grossed amount. I cant figure out how to get only the top values.

Comment: consider rephrasing this  MAX(ROUND(Grossed, 2)) AS Grossed to  MAX(ROUND(prodGross .Grossed, 2)) AS maxGrossed   for a start

Answer (score 0):

Consider derived tables of both aggregate queries matching the *CategoryID* and *Grossed* fields:

```
SELECT p.*, c.CategoryName, ROUND(g.MaxGrossed) AS HighestGrossed
FROM category c
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT subp.ProductID, subp.ProductName, subp.CategoryID,
          SUM(((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) - 
              ((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * od.Discount))) AS Grossed
   FROM northwind.`order details` AS od
   INNER JOIN products AS subp ON subp.ProductID = od.ProductID
   GROUP BY subp.ProductID) As p
ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID

INNER JOIN
   (SELECT subg.CategoryID, MAX(subg.Grossed) AS MaxGrossed
    FROM
      (SELECT subp.ProductID, subp.ProductName, subp.CategoryID,
              SUM(((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) - 
                  ((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * od.Discount))) AS Grossed
       FROM northwind.`order details` AS od
       INNER JOIN products AS subp ON subp.ProductID = od.ProductID
       GROUP BY subp.ProductID) AS subg
    GROUP BY subg.CategoryID) AS g
ON p.CategoryID = g.CategoryID AND p.Grossed = g.MaxGrossed
```

You can even save the repeated aggregate that calculates *Grossed* as a separate stored view and reference it in this query:

```
SELECT p.*, c.CategoryName, ROUND(g.MaxGrossed) AS HighestGrossed
FROM category c

INNER JOIN ProdGrossedView As p
ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID

INNER JOIN
   (SELECT v.CategoryID, MAX(v.Grossed) AS MaxGrossed
    FROM ProdGrossedView v
    GROUP BY v.CategoryID) AS g
ON p.CategoryID = g.CategoryID AND p.Grossed = g.MaxGrossed
```